# Angular Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular

I am not understanding an issue here. I have to use temp var as it causes issues in other parts of code.

```
public orgTemp: any = null;
public orgList!: Array <Organization>;


errors:
this.api.ListOrganizations().then(event => {
  this.orgList = event.items;

works:
this.api.ListOrganizations().then(event => {
  this.orgTemp = event.items;
  this.orgList = this.orgTemp;
```

Comment: you have misstyping in your variables naming

Comment: orgList!  !== this.orgList

Comment: clarify my question.  I am getting an array of org objects from my api.  But setting a var as  array of same types errors.  Creating a var of any loads just the array of values.

Comment: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Organization[]'.

29       this.orgList = event.items;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: just dont want to use type of "any".

Comment: Based on AWS angular example

Comment: I should be able to  /* declare restaurants variable */
  restaurants: Array<Restaurant>; and then

    /* fetch restaurants when app loads */
    this.api.ListRestaurants().then(event => {
      this.restaurants = event.items;
    });
  }